# Mac M1: Dnsmasq not resolving the local host on new apple m1 chip

Tags: apple-m1, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup my M1 laptop for dev env. But some dnsmasq is not working. I executed the following commands for dnsmasq:

- brew install dnsmasq
- echo 'address=/.local/127.0.0.1' > /opt/homebrew/etc/dnsmasq.conf
- sudo brew services start dnsmasq
- sudo brew services list

But when I try to ping to my local it's not responding.

`$ ping test90.local`

`ping: cannot resolve test90.local: Unknown host`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What DNS is ping using to resolve the hostname?

I'm not a mac user, but on BSD and Linux my next step would be to check /etc/resolv.conf to see if 127.0.0.1 was in the list of domains.

Also, .local is reserved for mdns. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local